# Looking for a way to make a java method I wrote more efficient if it possible

Tags: java, javafx

```
 private void setIsSelected() {

    if (option.equals("length")) {
        isSelectedLength.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        isSelectedLength.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (option.equals("weight")) {
        isSelectedWeight.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        isSelectedWeight.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (option.equals("temp")) {
        isSelectedTemp.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        isSelectedTemp.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (option.equals("area")) {
        isSelectedArea.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        isSelectedArea.setVisible(false);
    }
    if (option.equals("time")) {
        isSelectedTime.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        isSelectedTime.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I feel as if there is a better and more cleaner way of making this method work. The if else statements work however it kind of feels as if I am repeating myself. Any suggestion are gladly welcomed.

Comment: You could use a case statement or a hashmap mapping options and their values to option handlers.

Comment: A correct answer to this question would depend on knowing what `option` is and what the current class is.

Comment: Does anyone know what i'm getting downvoted, i can even upvote lol. Some people are super salty on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to do is use the value of `option.equals(...)` in the setters:

```
isSelectedLength.setVisible(option.equals("length"));
isSelectedWeight.setVisible(option.equals("weight"));
isSelectedTemp.setVisible(option.equals("temp"));
isSelectedArea.setVisible(option.equals("area"));
isSelectedTime.setVisible(option.equals("time"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the nodes in a `Map<String, Node>` to make the code of the method shorter/less repetitive:

```
Map<String, Node> nodesByString = new HashMap<>();
nodesByString.put("length", isSelectedLength);
nodesByString.put("weight", isSelectedWeight);
...
```

```
private void setIsSelected() {
    for (Node n : nodesByString.values()) {
        node.setVisible(false);
    }

    Node visibleNode = nodesByString.get(option);
    if (visibleNode != null) {
        visibleNode.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```